# Someone who's unable to speak / speak and hear in modern English

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

I was wondering what do native speakers normally call someone who is unable to speak in modern English.

I know the words "[dumb](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/dumb)" and "[mute](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/mute) which perhaps according to the dictionaries, it is dated and even impolite.

Also I need to know what do you call someone who is unable to speak and hear at the same time.

I wonder what is the safest and more common way to address such people.

Comment: Because ***dumb*** has been metaphorically extended to mean ***stupid***, you might prefer ***mute***. More often used as a noun that an adjective, when applied to a *person* who lacks the power of speech: *He is **a** mute* (where article-less *He is mute* would often imply *not speaking **right now***, rather than as a permanent condition).

Comment: But "mute" is old-fashioned as well @FumbleFingers. (Added to the thread)

Comment: [what native speakers normally call someone]

Comment: "Polite" Anglophones today would rarely use a ***noun*** for such contexts. We'd say *John cannot speak*, not *John is a mute*.

Comment: Then may I ask you what is the fixed term / expression to describe a person unable to speak and deaf at the same time?

Comment: 'Dumb' has _less_ of a connotation of stupidity in British than in American English, but is still considered incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been pointed out, **dumb** has fallen out of favor and the preferred term is **mute**. This is an example of the so-called [euphemism treadmill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Euphemism_treadmill); as you have pointed out, "dumb" used to be perfectly fine, but now it can seem offensive. Similarly **moron** and (I believe) **retard** used to be medical terms for people with IQs below a certain level, but now are only ever used as very offensive insults.

I would call someone who can neither hear nor speak a **deaf-mute**. And as Fumble pointed out, it is often better to refer to someone as a *person* rather than *a collection of inabilities*, so "a person who can't hear or speak" might be better.

Answer (score 2):

You would not use a noun.

There are many conditions that can result in a person being unable to speak: Strokes, and other forms of brain damage.  Deafness in some cases (though the deaf person may sign even though they didn't learn to speak). Physical deformaties of the jaw or throat. Psychological conditions,  and probably many others.

There is no reason to lump these together. Instead you'd just say, for example:

> Lucy had a stroke and is unable to speak.